# How to compile OpenSSL version 1.0.2 using Borland C++ Builder 6 on Windows XP SP3?

Tags: openssl, c++builder, c++builder-6

I have found that the documentation for OpenSSL 1.0.2 suggests compiling it using Borland C++Builder 5. However, when I attempted to compile it using Borland C++Builder 6, I encountered the following error message:

```
bcc32 -otmp32\cryptlib.obj -Iinc32 -Itmp32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -q -w-ccc -w-rch -w-pia -w-aus -w-par -w-inl -c -tWC -tWM -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DL_ENDIAN -DDSO_WIN32 -D_stricmp=stricmp -D_
strnicmp=strnicmp -O2 -ff -fp -DBN_ASM -DMD5_NO_ASM -DSHA1_NO_ASM -DRMD160_NO_ASM -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS
 -DOPENSSL_NO_DYNAMIC_ENGINE  -c .\crypto\cryptlib.c
.\crypto\cryptlib.c:
Error E2141 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 232: Declaration syntax error
Error E2139 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 327: Declaration missing ;
Error E2238 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 328: Multiple declaration for 'sockaddr_gen'
Error E2344 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 327: Earlier declaration of 'sockaddr_gen'
Error E2139 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 328: Declaration missing ;
Error E2238 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 329: Multiple declaration for 'sockaddr_gen'
Error E2344 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 327: Earlier declaration of 'sockaddr_gen'
Error E2139 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 329: Declaration missing ;
Error E2141 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 469: Declaration syntax error
Error E2303 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\ws2tcpip.h 519: Type name expected
Error E2303 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 39: Type name expected
Error E2303 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 666: Type name expected
Error E2141 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 866: Declaration syntax error in function WspiapiLoad
Error E2451 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 867: Undefined symbol 'rgtGlobal' in function WspiapiLoad
Error E2109 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 867: Not an allowed type in function WspiapiLoad
Warning W8019 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 871: Code has no effect in function WspiapiLoad
Error E2379 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 871: Statement missing ; in function WspiapiLoad
Error E2140 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 872: Declaration is not allowed here in function WspiapiLoad
Error E2140 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 873: Declaration is not allowed here in function WspiapiLoad
Error E2451 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 933: Undefined symbol 'rgtLocal' in function WspiapiLoad
Error E2303 C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Include\wspiapi.h 981: Type name expected
*** 20 errors in Compile ***
```

How can I fix this problem?

I expect it to compile correctly.

Comment: A bunch of those errors happen when code `#include`'s both `<winsock.h>` and `<winsock2.h>` in the same translation unit, and `<winsock.h>` is `#include`'d first.  Those two headers are not meant to coexist together. `<winsock2.h>` is a *replacement* for `<winsock.h>`. It will disable `<winsock.h>` if `#include`'d first, and all is well. But if `<winsock.h>` is included first, the compile fails since `<winsock.h>` has no concept of `<winsock2.h>` and `<winsock2.h>` redeclares a bunch of things that already exist in `<winsock.h>`.